# How to validate XML document against DTD while having multiple levels?

Tags: xml, dtd

I know how to validate XML document against DTD with single level but, How we can do it when data is nested (multiple level). The root is `chapters` and under root I have two main elements `chapter1` and `chapter2` and under each I have sub-elements. The name of these sub-elements are identical in both `chapter1` and `chapter2`. My question is: Do I need to declare the `<!ELEMENT mainTopic CDATA #REQUIRED >` once or twice in order, under each `chapter1` and `chapter2` declaration?

```
<chapters>
    <chapter1>
        <mainTopic>HTML MARKUP AND DOCUMENT STRUCTURE</mainTopic>
        <subTopic1>The Basics of Markup</subTopic1>
        <subTopic2>Anatomy of an HTML Document</subTopic2>
        <subTopic3>The Document Object Model</subTopic3>
    </chapter1>
    <chapter2>
        <mainTopic>HOW CSS WORKS</mainTopic>
        <subTopic1>The Anatomy of CSS Rule</subTopic1>
        <subTopic2>Contexual Selectors</subTopic2>
        <subTopic3>Specialized Contextual Selectors</subTopic3>
        <subTopic4>IDs and Classes</subTopic4>
        <subTopic5>Attibute Selectors</subTopic5>
        <subTopic6>Pseduo-Classes</subTopic6>
        <subTopic7>Pseduo-Elements</subTopic7>
        <subTopic8>Inheritance</subTopic8>
        <subTopic9>The Cascade</subTopic9>
        <subTopic10>Rule Declaration</subTopic10>
    </chapter2>
</chapters>
```

The following is the inline-DTD code:

```
<!DOCTYPE chapters [
    <!ELEMENT chapters (chapter1, chapter2)>

    <!ELEMENT chapters (chapter1, chapter2) >
    <!ELEMENT chapter1 (mainTopic, subTopic1, subTopic2, subTopic3) >

    <!ELEMENT chapter2 (mainTopic, subTopic1, subTopic2, subTopic3, subTopic4, subTopic5, subTopic6, subTopic7, subTopic8, subTopic9, subTopic10) >
    <!ELEMENT mainTopic (#PCDATA) >
    <!ELEMENT subTopic1 (#PCDATA) >
    <!ELEMENT subTopic2 (#PCDATA) >
    <!ELEMENT subTopic3 (#PCDATA) >
    <!ELEMENT subTopic4 (#PCDATA) >
    <!ELEMENT subTopic5 (#PCDATA) >
    <!ELEMENT subTopic6 (#PCDATA) >
    <!ELEMENT subTopic7 (#PCDATA) >
    <!ELEMENT subTopic8 (#PCDATA) >
    <!ELEMENT subTopic9 (#PCDATA) >
    <!ELEMENT subTopic10 (#PCDATA) >
]>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to declare the `<!ELEMENT mainTopic CDATA #REQUIRED >` once or
>   twice in order, under each `chapter1` and `chapter2` declaration?

You are only allowed to declare the element once. Your declaration for `mainTopic` in your example DTD is correct. (The declaration in the quote above is not.)

Your DTD and instance are valid if you remove the second declaration for `chapters`...

```
<!DOCTYPE chapters [
    <!ELEMENT chapters (chapter1, chapter2)>

    <!ELEMENT chapter1 (mainTopic, subTopic1, subTopic2, subTopic3) >

    <!ELEMENT chapter2 (mainTopic, subTopic1, subTopic2, subTopic3, subTopic4, subTopic5, subTopic6, subTopic7, subTopic8, subTopic9, subTopic10) >
    <!ELEMENT mainTopic (#PCDATA) >
    <!ELEMENT subTopic1 (#PCDATA) >
    <!ELEMENT subTopic2 (#PCDATA) >
    <!ELEMENT subTopic3 (#PCDATA) >
    <!ELEMENT subTopic4 (#PCDATA) >
    <!ELEMENT subTopic5 (#PCDATA) >
    <!ELEMENT subTopic6 (#PCDATA) >
    <!ELEMENT subTopic7 (#PCDATA) >
    <!ELEMENT subTopic8 (#PCDATA) >
    <!ELEMENT subTopic9 (#PCDATA) >
    <!ELEMENT subTopic10 (#PCDATA) >
]>
```

Off topic; if you have control over the DTD and XML, I would strongly suggest not declaring separate `chapter#` and `subTopic#` elements (with the trailing number). Nothing is gained by this. I would only declare single `chapter` and `subTopic` elements...

```
<!DOCTYPE chapters [
<!ELEMENT chapters (chapter+)>
<!ELEMENT chapter (mainTopic, subTopic+)>
<!ELEMENT mainTopic (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT subTopic (#PCDATA)>
]>
<chapters>
    <chapter>
        <mainTopic>HTML MARKUP AND DOCUMENT STRUCTURE</mainTopic>
        <subTopic>The Basics of Markup</subTopic>
        <subTopic>Anatomy of an HTML Document</subTopic>
        <subTopic>The Document Object Model</subTopic>
    </chapter>
    <chapter>
        <mainTopic>HOW CSS WORKS</mainTopic>
        <subTopic>The Anatomy of CSS Rule</subTopic>
        <subTopic>Contexual Selectors</subTopic>
        <subTopic>Specialized Contextual Selectors</subTopic>
        <subTopic>IDs and Classes</subTopic>
        <subTopic>Attibute Selectors</subTopic>
        <subTopic>Pseduo-Classes</subTopic>
        <subTopic>Pseduo-Elements</subTopic>
        <subTopic>Inheritance</subTopic>
        <subTopic>The Cascade</subTopic>
        <subTopic>Rule Declaration</subTopic>
    </chapter>
</chapters>
```